# Run time error when clicking cancel on Input box asking for Date

Tags: vba, ms-access

The end result of this is a time sheet.  I put it together initially in excel, but I'm looking to move the payroll information/module into access.  When I am in excel the cancel button works fine, but in access it always errors. Some research on line shows this is a problem which I thought I could solve with something akin to

```
 If StartDate = "" Then
  GoTo ext:
  End If
```

This causes

> run time error 13.

This occurs I believe because when one hits cancel the StartDate variable is empty and the input box is expecting some type of input.  I'll keep looking on line, but perhaps the issue is I should not be using an Input Box, but if that is the case I'm not sure what should be used?  The full script is below.  Any help is appreciated.

```
Private Sub CreateTimeSheet_Click()

Dim StartDate As Date

mbox = InputBox("Enter Start Date YYYY/MM/DD", "Enter Start Date")
StartDate = mbox

  If StartDate = "" Then
  GoTo ext:
  End If

FirstDay = Format(CDate(StartDate))
Text76 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 1))
Text77 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 2))
Text78 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 3))
Text79 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 4))
Text80 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 5))
Text81 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 6))
Text82 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 7))
Text83 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 8))
Text84 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 9))
Text85 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 10))
Text86 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 11))
Text87 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 12))
Text88 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 13))

Text61 = Format(CDate(mbox), "dddd")
Text63 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 1), "dddd")
Text64 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 2), "dddd")
Text65 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 3), "dddd")
Text66 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 4), "dddd")
Text67 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 5), "dddd")
Text68 = Format(CDate(StartDate + 6), "dddd")
Text69 = Text61.value
Text70 = Text63.value
Text71 = Text64.value
Text72 = Text65.value
Text73 = Text66.value
Text74 = Text67.value
Text75 = Text68.value

ext:
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Since `InputBox` returns a `String` you will want to store the result into a `String`, not a `Date` variable. Then you can use `IsDate()` to check to see if that result text can be converted to a `Date`. Then and only then continue, otherwise, exit. Keep in mind the user can enter anything they way into the `InputBox` - You cannot depend on them entering an actual date value.

Comment: `""` is not a `Date`

Comment: Also if `End Sub` is directly after `Exit Sub` then you don't actually need the `Exit Sub` - it's going to hit the `End Sub` straight after it bounces to `ext:` anyway. I think what you were originally after was the one-liner `If StartDate = "" Then Exit Sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `InputBox` returns a `String` you will want to store the result into a `String`, not a `Date` variable. Then you can use `IsDate()` to check to see if that result text can be converted to a Date. Then and only then continue, otherwise, exit. Keep in mind the user can enter anything they way into the `InputBox` - You cannot depend on them entering an actual date value.

```
Dim mbox As String
Dim StartDate As Date

mbox = InputBox("Enter Start Date YYYY/MM/DD", "Enter Start Date")
If IsDate(mbox) Then
  StartDate = CDate(mbox)
Else
  If mbox = "" Then
    ' user entered nothing, so cancel
    Exit Sub
  Else
    ' user entered garbage, so tell them what they did wrong
    MsgBox "That is not a date."
    Exit Sub
  End If
End If

' valid data entered... rest of your code here
```

Also, if you are adding days to a date value, you will want to use [DateAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function), not simple addition.